# Can a model belong to many models which has_one of the first model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations, has-one

I have two tables.
`users`
`superpowers`

I want each `user` to be limited to one `superpower`. But different `users` can have the same `superpower`. (sam can have fire, john can have lightning, sarah can also have lightning. But every user can only have one super power)

I want to store the foreign key in the user table.

Will a `has_one` and `belongs_to` relationship be suitable for this?

`user` `has_one` `superpower`.
`superpower` `belongs_to` `user`

The rails guide says has_one sets up a one to one relationship. But a subtle nuance is not addressed: whether the "belonging" model (i.e. `superpowers) can belong to multiple "has_one-ing" models (i.e.`users`), where each association is a one-to-one relationship (e.g. john has lightning, and sarah also has lightning).

OR, does it mean that both the "belonging" model and the "having" model must both be unique in all associations? (e.g. if john has lighting, sarah cannot have lightning)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your description (especially the part about foreign key being in `users` table), the relationship should be:

```
Superpower.has_many :users
User.belongs_to :superpower
```

The `belongs_to` part of association is always at the model with foreign key.

Comment: I would normally do it that way too, but then my superpowers will have a variable number of columns, equal to the number of users. it will keep growing, which is no good. Since the limit is a user having one superpower, i wish to key the foreign key in the user table, not the other way.

Comment: Just in case i'm not using the proper wording, when i say foreign key is in the users table, i mean the users table has a column containing the id of a superpower.

Comment: @gwho so I understood it properly. What I don't understand is your statement about growing numer of columns in `superpowers` table. Could you explain what you mean?

Comment: oh, right. "The belongs_to part of association is always at the model with foreign key."

So... since that would not satisfy my design preference, is it best if I use to a has_many :through association?

Comment: if i store the foreign key of the user in the superpowers table, i would imagine that would mean a superpower record/row would contain as many columns as there are users that have that superpower. I wish to keep increasing the number of users. am i wrong about this?

Comment: nevermind. i was confused. I was thinking of the other way around.

Thank you very much, Marek.

Comment: @gwho God, no, following your requirements, the associations from my answer are perfect. Using complications like `has_man :through` is complete nonsense here. 
And no, for this association it's enough you have `superpower_id` column in `users` table to work. You don't need separate column for every user in `superpowers` table (what's more, you don't need any user-related column in this table).

Comment: Now just for funsies, if i wanted this same setup, except I wanted the foreign key to be in the superpowers table, would that be a set of requirements that rails wouldn't be able to satisfy? perhaps just bad table design in general? It sounds like bad design in general.

Comment: @gwho it's not that Rails wouldn't be able to satisfy your requirements with this schema - it would be logically impossible. If you store `user_id` in `superpowers` table, your superpower is connected always with one user (and single user can be connected with many superpowers).
Your table design in general seems to be good since it complies with your current requirements (when this association's foreign key is in `users` table, of course).